# Self hosting SignalR in linqpad

Tags: signalr, linqpad

## Scenario

I'm attempting to use linqpad to self host SignalR.

## Script

```
// I have uploaded to instant share here: http://share.linqpad.net/578ol2.linq 

// Import the following nuget packages:
// Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost
// Microsoft.Owin.Cors

#define NONEST

void Main()
{
    var baseUrl = @"http://localhost:8080/";

    using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUrl))
    {
        Process.Start(baseUrl + "index.html");

        Console.WriteLine("Server running at " + baseUrl);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public readonly string Html = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <input type='text' id='message' />
        <input type='button' id='sendmessage' value='Send' />
        <input type='hidden' id='displayname' />
        <ul id='discussion'></ul>
    </div>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.0.js'></script>
    <script src='http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8080/signalr';
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;

            var chat = $.connection.myHub;

            chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };

            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            $('#message').focus();

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
".Trim();

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();

        app.Map("/index.html", config =>
        {
            config.Run(context => 
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(Html);
            });
        });
    }
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

## Outcome

If you look at the browser console you see that SignalR eventually exhausts all transports, so can't create a connection between the client and the server

```
SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'myhub'.
Negotiating with 'http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D'.
serverSentEvents transport starting.
Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProt…joHW8a9m5Q%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&tid=1'.
EventSource connected.
serverSentEvents transport timed out when trying to connect.
EventSource calling close().
serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
foreverFrame transport starting.
Forever Frame is not supported by SignalR on browsers with SSE support.
foreverFrame transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
longPolling transport starting.
Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8080/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=…QeRv75joHW8a9m5Q%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D'.
longPolling transport timed out when trying to connect.
Aborted xhr request.
longPolling transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
Fallback transports exhausted.
Stopping connection.
Fired ajax abort async = true.
```

***However this same exact code works without issue within a Console Application***

## Question

Does anyone know why this code fails when hosting in linqpad but works when hosting in a console application?

Comment: What's your LinqPad version?

Comment: I am using Linqpad 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaning towards some sort of connectivity issue rather than a LinqPad one as I'm able to run your code snipped without an issue. I am also running it under version 5. Do you happen to have a 3r party firewall?

Just to confirm, what's the expected behaviour? When I run it, my browser pops up asking me to enter a name. Then I'm able to send 'messages', which appear on the page below the text box.

Comment: Just testing it again and it appears to be working now .. thanks for your help